# send value with pageobject c# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to create a function that will find an element with text inside the dom document.

This is how I'm I trying to achieve this:

`IWebElement` in PageObject:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[contains(text()")] 
IWebElement getText { get; set; }
```

`IWebElement` extension method:

```
public static void containsText(this IWebElement element, string value)
{
    element.FindElement(By.XPath(",'" + value + "')]"));
}
```

Method:

```
public AutomationPage findText()
{
    getText.containsText("test")
}
```

So what I'm trying to achive is that the method should find the entire Xpath.

Correct output should be:

```
"//*[contains(text(),'test')]"
```

but it gives me:

> Could not find element by: By.XPath: //*[contains(text()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work like you're expecting. Basically, you're trying to find an element with xpath `//*[contains(text()` and then you're trying to find a child element with the xpath `,'test')]`. Neither of which is a valid xpath.

For dynamic `xpaths`, it's better to use a function rather than `FindsBy`

Something like this:

```
private IWebElement GetElementContainsText(string text)
{
    return driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), '" + text + "')];
}
```

Long story short, you have to construct your selector before creating your `By` and before calling `FindElement`

I can understand the sadness in letting go of the `FindsBy` in these scenarios, as well as the sadness of not being able to use a cool **extension** method. I really wish I had a solution that would do things the way you're trying to do them, but from what I've seen the above is the correct approach in these cases. Cheers :)

Comment: Hey! I'm not so sad anymore;) because this works really really good. 
Thank you so much for explanation and hints.